# Elixir - call a module function from the shell

Tags: shell, elixir, elixir-iex

In Elixir, is there a way to call a module function directly from the shell, without necessarily needing to start an `iex -S mix` session? Let me illustrate with a scenario:

As part of my Phoenix app, I've written a helper module that is to be run from an adjacent `iex -S mix` session. Here's a super-simplified version:

```
defmodule MyApp.Helper do
  # For the demo, these imports/aliases are not used - but they're there in real life.
  import Ecto.Query
  alias MyApp.Repo

  def start do
    {:ok, "Done"}
  end
end
```

If I start the session with `iex -S mix` and then run a function from the module, it all works fine:

```
$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Compiling 2 files (.ex)
Interactive Elixir (1.5.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> MyApp.Helper.start
{:ok, "Done"}
```

And then `ctrl-c a` to close the session.

However, if I try something like:

```
$ iex -S mix MyApp.Helper.start
```

That results in

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Compiling 2 files (.ex)
** (Mix) The task "MyApp.Helper.start" could not be found
```

Alternately, I tried redefining my module as a custom mix task, as described here: https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/mix-tasks/#custom-mix-task

but that also failed, because my module depends on some imports/aliases like `MyApp.Repo`, and trying to execute the file with either `mix helper` or `iex -S mix helper` resulted in

```
** (ArgumentError) repo MyApp.Repo is not started, please ensure it is part of your supervision tree
```

If there's no way around this and the script can only be successfully executed from within a running `iex -S mix`, that's fine... but if there was a way to set things up so a one-liner could run from the shell to get this to execute as-needed, that'd be the bee's knees.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `mix run` with the `-e` argument for this:

```
$ mix run -e MyApp.Helper.start
```

or if you have arguments to pass to the function:

```
$ mix run -e "MyApp.Helper.start(:foo, :bar)"
```

From `mix help run`:

> If there is a desire to execute a script within the current
>   application or configure the application via command line flags, it is
>   possible to do so by passing a script file or an eval expression to
>   the command:
>
> ```
> mix run my_app_script.exs arg1 arg2 arg3
> mix run -e "MyApp.start" -- arg1 arg2 arg3
> ```

Comment: +1 — worth adding that if you want to run a one-liner outside a mix project you can pass `--no-mix-exs` as an argument; e.g: `mix run --no-mix-exs -e 'IO.puts(:hello)'`